# how to two know two factor authentication status of a user signing in through google

Tags: javascript, google-signin

We are building a website which required two factor authentication. We are planning to provide google log in as well but in case they have set up 2FA on google login, we want to skip our second step. I am not able to see anything on the docs which enables me know a user's 2FA status on google. Is there a way?

Comment: Basically you either trust Google's authentication (and ignore whether the user uses 2FA on google) or you do your own.  At the point you delegate to Google, you shouldn't care about 2FA and you trust that Google has enough information to properly authenticate the user (regardless of the user's 2FA status with Google.)\

Comment: Let's say we are regulated to have a two factor authentication for our users. Now if we provide google login for UX purposes, and add a second step of our own after that then in the case there the user has 2FA enabled, he goes through three steps which we deem bad. Hence wanted to discover the possibility.

Comment: My point is: when you introduce google as an authentication provider, you are *no longer the authentication source for the user, Google is*  It is up to Google and your user in that case whether or not they should use 2FA.  If you have a strict 2FA requirement, then either you do your own 2FA regardless or you don't use Google auth.

Comment: I get the point but there are many reasons to go for google auth and if 2FA is a requirement, it would be great if google provides the 2FA auth status. It is a vital piece of information to make a certain kind of auth flow work with good UX, much like email and family name which google readily provides.